# Can Jdownloader be installed into text mode in linux without X11?

Tags: linux, installation, gentoo, text

I'm insterested into installing Jdownloader into text mode in linux, i want to use the api it has to control the downloads from a web application
Do you guys think that's possible in gentoo? if so , how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does *run* without a proper value for `$DISPLAY`, but configuring it to use one of the interfaces may be tricky. Not to mention handling CAPTCHAs.

Comment: yes actually i wanted to use it for normal HTTP downloads, nothing special , just provide some cookies, or u/p and that's it 
Meanwhile i've found another solution it's called Aria2 .
This one has an xml-rpc protocol and runs without X11. Do you know something about it?

Comment: Never heard of it.

Comment: here's a link http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/aria2/wiki
looks...pretty primising, has a web interface as well, cool